# How to fill richtextbox from memory stream?

Tags: c#

I want to fill richtext box with the values of a text file. The text file will come from the database.
I have done this code so far.

```
 Byte[] txtdata = (Byte[])(objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][7]);
 MemoryStream txtmem = new MemoryStream(txtdata);
 richTextBox_Show_Spec.LoadFile(txtmem,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

But nothing shows in that richtextbox.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I've solved my problem. I just replaced RichText with Plaintext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the `Encoding` namespace to get a character string from your bytes.  Like `richTextBox.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(txtmem.ToArray());`
 or similar.

That way you can still store formatting information should you ever choose to support things like text size or color.